# Need help for a new tag creation

Tags: support

Can someone help by creating tag named [microsoft-dynamics-crm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-dynamics-crm) similar to [microsoft-dynamics-gp](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-dynamics-gp) as they are different products?

Right now all the questions are tagged into gp product tag itself as there is no crm product tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've retagged an obvious question with the new tag, [microsoft-dynamics-crm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-dynamics-crm). You should be able to suggest edits to every other question which needs to be retagged.